Java Web Services Error al hacer el deploy xml:1049
He estado avanzando con un proyecto usando web service, y funcionaba bien hasta que agregue un segundo web service, y al momento de hacer un deploy me sale error:
init:
deps-module-jar:
deps-ear-jar:
deps-jar:
library-inclusion-in-archive:
library-inclusion-in-manifest:
compile:
compile-jsps:
In-place deployment at 
C:\Users\PC01\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Clinica\build\web
GlassFish Server 4.1.1, deploy, null, false
C:\Users\PC01\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Clinica\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1049: The module has not been deployed.                                                   
See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

Intente hacerle un clean and build, reiniciando el servidor GlassFish, y lo hace correctamente pero cuando le doy a deploy me tira el mismo error. Al abrir el xml me dirige aquí:
    <target if="netbeans.home" name="-run-deploy-nb">
        <nbdeploy clientUrlPart="${client.urlPart}" debugmode="false" forceRedeploy="${forceRedeploy}"/>
    </target>

También intenté con otros IDE pero el resultado es el mismo.
En cuanto a los registros del servidor, creo que son estos, perdón si me estoy equivocando.
[2024-05-12T12:31:25.615-0500] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] [NCLS-SECURITY-05054] [javax.enterprise.system.security.ssl] [tid: _ThreadID=51 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1715535085615] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  The SSL certificate has expired: [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=Thawte Timestamping CA, OU=Thawte Certification, O=Thawte, L=Durbanville, ST=Western Cape, C=ZA
  Signature Algorithm: MD5withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.4

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 1024 bits
  modulus: 150394810126050534195607348771257688618226830439427012944317605301871780585155880224059919275918092942113826771457306002168961528354555410811499383007163869667256402121606010388051928897681658302241334246227013894619095367906998686005623619895444985599269532138452649990612009700935363403449682782499603253303
  public exponent: 65537
  Validity: [From: Tue Dec 31 19:00:00 COT 1996,
               To: Thu Dec 31 18:59:59 COT 2020]
  Issuer: CN=Thawte Timestamping CA, OU=Thawte Certification, O=Thawte, L=Durbanville, ST=Western Cape, C=ZA
  SerialNumber: [    00]

Certificate Extensions: 1
[1]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=true
BasicConstraints:[
  CA:true
  PathLen:2147483647
]

]
  Algorithm: [MD5withRSA]
  Signature:
0000: 67 DB E2 C2 E6 87 3D 40   83 86 37 35 7D 1F CE 9A  g.....=@..75....
0010: C3 0C 66 20 A8 BA AA 04   89 86 C2 F5 10 08 0D BF  ..f ............
0020: CB A2 05 8A D0 4D 36 3E   F4 D7 EF 69 C6 5E E4 B0  .....M6>...i.^..
0030: 94 6F 4A B9 E7 DE 5B 88   B6 7B DB E3 27 E5 76 C3  .oJ...[.....'.v.
0040: F0 35 C1 CB B5 27 9B 33   79 DC 90 A6 00 9E 77 FA  .5...'.3y.....w.
0050: FC CD 27 94 42 16 9C D3   1C 68 EC BF 5C DD E5 A9  ..'.B....h..\...
0060: 7B 10 0A 32 74 54 13 31   8B 85 03 84 91 B7 58 01  ...2tT.1......X.
0070: 30 14 38 AF 28 CA FC B1   50 19 19 09 AC 89 49 D3  0.8.(...P.....I.

]]]


Buenas, Francis, ¿puedes buscar el fichero de log del servidor y pegar aquí el error? Con lo que has puesto poco se puede hacer
